# Create a custom uiView like UiActionSheet in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiactionsheet

[image]
  I want show an ActionSheet to show an create account on map I can implement this in ipad by using the ShowFromRect method but, behavior of ShowFromRect is not defined for Iphone or it has default bahaviour which is it pops up from the bottom of the view but I want to show the ActionSheet on the map wherever the user clicks on the map. How can I implement this? Or is it like I have to create a custom UIView like the UIActionSheet with the arrow pointing down towards the location user selects on the Map. If so how can I create a custom UIView for this purpose?
         I have attached a demo image to show how I want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

may be this solution help you...i read this somewhere..You can do this using an actionsheet.
First declare a property of uiactionsheet at the interface. In below example I have declared a property named countryActionSheet.

after that in the IBaction follow the code;

```
 -(IBAction)popupView{//  declare another actionSheet //
UIActionSheet *actionSheet =[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select Country"       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

countryActionsheet=actionSheet;//equate both the actionSheets//

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle= UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
countryPicker.dataSource=self;
countryPicker.delegate=self; 

// Add your view with frame with respect to actionSheet//

UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"black background.png"];

UIButton *cancelBtn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,20, 80, 30)];
[cancelBtn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];// create a method named cancelBtnPressed
[cancelBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled 4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIButton *okBtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 80, 30)];
[okBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[okBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[okBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(okBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];// create method named okBtnPressed
[okBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled 4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[countryActionsheet addSubview:imageView];
[countryActionsheet addSubview:cancelBtn];
[countryActionsheet addSubview:okBtn];

[countryActionsheet showInView:self.view];
[countryActionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];// frame of actionSheet
}

-(void)cancelbtnPressed{
     // write action
}

-(void)okBtnPressed{
     // write action
}
```

Hope this might help you;

Comment: let me know..did you solve your issue or not..@Nikhil